# BASH How to get first number in a string of a file

Tags: linux, bash

I am wondering how I can grab a text file, parse the first line and look for the first date or number in format **mm/dd/yyyy** so **04/10/2020** and then have it reorganized in a different output text file.

so for example in a text file (**list.txt**) containing:

```
john's birthday 4/20/2020
Finish reading "the one thing" 4/10/2020
verify video has been posted 5/25/2020
4/15/2020 call bob
```

Desired output:

```
Finish reading "the one thing" 4/10/2020
4/15/2020 call bob 
john's birthday 4/20/2020
verify video has been posted 5/25/2020
```

My pseudocode is below and but I have gotten stuck on how to use regular expressions to ignore '/' and then what the best method to continue

```
# pseudocode
# 1. Read and output each line
# get the first number
# make sure to ignore the '/' or '-' for date
# get the new value strung together and sort it
# store that line number in an array
# sort it
# output the lines in the array order

    while read line
  do
      nline=$(echo $line | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'| head -1)
      echo $nline

  done < list2.txt
```

Comment: Why do you want to ignore `/`? Include it: `[0-9/]+`

Comment: There's no need for `head -1`, since you're only echoing one line.

Comment: Always put your variables in quotes unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: what is your desired sort criteria? you state the dates are in `DD/MM/YYYY` format but your sample data shows `MM/DD/YYYY` (w/ single digit months missing the leading 0); if sorting as `MM/DD/YYYY` (sans leading 0 for months), then you could get `11/04/2020` coming before `3/01/2020` (depending on your sort method)

Comment: @markp-fuso sorry I mistyped, it was MM/DD/YYYY
@Barmar What if I had another date in there like `4/16/2020 or 4/17/2020 call sally `; would I use head -1 then ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution may  work for you:

```
paste <( grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*" list.txt  ) list.txt | sort -n -t/ -k3,3 -k1,1 -k2,2 | cut -f2-
```

To understand this solution, it's helpful to review the command incrementally adding pipe commands.  Let's review the parts:

```
$ grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*" list.txt
4/20/2020
4/10/2020
5/25/2020
4/15/2020
```

The `grep -o` extracts only the matching part of the string.
By surrounding the grep with `<()` , we create a temporary named pipe so that we can use it as an input file as follows:

```
paste <( grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*" list.txt) list.txt
```

The paste combines each line from the two files.  Essentially, we are prepending each line in list.txt with the date found on the line.

```
$ paste <( grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*" list.txt) list.txt
4/20/2020   john's birthday 4/20/2020
4/10/2020   Finish reading "the one thing" 4/10/2020
5/25/2020   verify video has been posted 5/25/2020
4/15/2020   4/15/2020 call bob
```

Here's an equivalent expression using `paste -` to read from stdin;

```
$ grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*" list.txt | paste -  list.txt
4/20/2020   john's birthday 4/20/2020
4/10/2020   Finish reading "the one thing" 4/10/2020
5/25/2020   verify video has been posted 5/25/2020
4/15/2020   4/15/2020 call bob
```

Now we can sort this output.  We are going to use / as the delimiter and make sure we sort by year first, then month, and then day using the -k options to sort.  It is also important to sort numerically (-n):

```
$ paste <( grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*" list.txt  ) list.txt | sort -n -t/ -k3,3 -k1,1 -k2,2 
4/10/2020   Finish reading "the one thing" 4/10/2020
4/15/2020   4/15/2020 call bob 
4/20/2020   john's birthday 4/20/2020
5/25/2020   verify video has been posted 5/25/2020
```

Now we're almost done.  We should delete the first column with the `cut` command.  Here we are displaying column 2 to the end (that is, we are deleting column 1):

```
$ paste <( grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*" list.txt  ) list.txt | sort -n -t/ -k3,3 -k1,1 -k2,2  | cut -f2-
Finish reading "the one thing" 4/10/2020
4/15/2020 call bob 
john's birthday 4/20/2020
verify video has been posted 5/25/2020
```

Comment: Sorry, still learning regular expressions. Can you walk me over what the following means  `"[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*"`? 
So my thought process is the first two - `[0-9][0-9]` are two digits
followed by `*/` which is saying to expect a `/` and same logic with the next set. 
How come the last 3 is just `[0-9][0-9]*` instead of `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`
Also can you explain all of `sort -n -t/ -k3,3 -k1,1 -k2,2`

Comment: The important take away is that `*` means 0 or more of the previous expression.  So `[0-9]` matches a single digit, and `[0-9][0-9]*` matches 1 or more digits.

Comment: You are right, the last bit should be `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`.  This ensures that you get a year in the YYYY format.  This makes the date sorting more robust.  Instead I made it more flexible by allowing 2-digit years to match.  This will match more dates , but it could lead to sorting issues if the data is inconsistent.

Comment: Thank you Mark. That was a very thorough and helpful explanation. Thank you for taking the time to type all that out. For future references, where can I go or what resources do you recommend I check out to learn more about regular expressions, finding words starting or ending in certain characters etc?

Comment: Regex is well documented on the web.  I don't have a favorite resource (having learned them 30 years ago).  You should be aware that there are different flavors of regexs. Make sure that you know if you are working with standard or enhanced.  Even limiting your searching to SO may find a useful link to regex guides.

Comment: Thank you Mark. One more question. if I had a date range for example a line containing: `call Mary 04/20/2020 - 04/21/2020` the grep command will take the `04/21/2020` and place it into the next line, how do I go about avoiding that?

Comment: The idea is we can remove any line that just has a date on it.  `paste <( grep -o "[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*" list.txt  | grep -v "^[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*/[0-9][0-9]*$" ) list.txt | sort -n -t/ -k3,3 -k1,1 -k2,2  | cut -f2-`

Comment: That addition of the second grep provided me a blank output. But from looking at it the second grep is suppose to remove anything that starts and ends with ##/##/## format?